# Slider height CSS does not work

Tags: css

For my website http://www.suemaisano.com/, I want to increase the homepage slider BACKGROUND IMAGE height (different than slider image, I did not set any slider image, only background image). I set the class as of the slider as homeSlider, and this is the code I put in the child CSS

```
.homeSlider .et_pb_slide .et_pb_container {
height: auto !important;
min-height: 1080px !important;}
```

However, the background image height did not change when I manipulated the min-height. The actual image sizes are ~1920x1080. Anything I need to change the code to make the min height work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no background-images. Do you wanna change height on a slide where text appear ?

Comment: Yes, I want to increase the height of the image where the text goes.

Comment: You may find [this link](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the image goes into the div where the text appears, the below should give you the height that you are aiming for.

```
.et_pb_slide_content {height: 1080px; }
```

Comment: No it didn't help... Now I wonder if the child theme CSS work at all...

Comment: strangely enough when I add this code it fixed it.                              homeslider .et_pb_slide .et_pb_container {
 height: 900 !important;
 min-height: 500px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height on description container

```
.homeSlider .et_pb_slide_description  {
    min-height: 1080px;
}
```